# authentication with Java and apache HttpClient 4.5.1

Tags: java, cookies, authentication, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

my problem is, that i don't get, how to log in with Java and Apache HttpComponents (HttpClient v4.5.1) into a specific site:  [Site im trying to log in](http://demo.studip.de/index.php?again=yes). I have the username (test_admin) and the password (testing) to log in but i think this is not enough and i need something more. I think this has something to do with the field security_token i see when i make a get request to the uri, but i dont know how to keep that or how to save that and what to do with it afterwards. There is also a hidden input field with the name login-ticket, but i dont know what's that for either. I want to login, because i need to see the courses and add some new ones. After trying with several code implementations im stick with this code:

```
    public static void setGet(CloseableHttpClient httpClient) throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException
{
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://demo.studip.de/dispatch.php/admin/courses");
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    System.out.println("GET Response Status:: "
            + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    showEntity(httpResponse,httpResponse.getEntity());

}


public static HttpEntity setParam(int count, String[] params, String[] values)
{
    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(params[i],values[i]));
        System.out.println("Paramater------------------> "+params[i]+"   Values-------------> "+values[i]);
    }   
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
    return entity;

}

public static void setPost(HttpClient httpC) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://demo.studip.de/dispatch.php/admin/courses");

    //String[] params = {"loginname", "password"};
    //String[] values = {"test_admin", "testing"};
    //HttpEntity entity = setParam(2, params, values );

    HttpResponse response = httpC.execute(httppost);
    System.out.println("POST Response Status:: "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    showEntity(response, response.getEntity());

}


public static void showEntity(HttpResponse httpResp, HttpEntity httpClient) throws IOException
{

        httpClient = httpResp.getEntity();
        if (httpClient != null) 
            httpClient = new BufferedHttpEntity(httpClient);

         System.out.print(EntityUtils.toString(httpClient));
}




 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

     CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
     credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
             new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test_admin", "testing"));
     CloseableHttpClient hc = 
     HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

     setGet(hc);
    // HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
     setPost(hc);
     setGet(hc);

    }
```

The problem now ist that i get everytime the same answer from the server i only see the login page in the response, where the server asks me to login with username and password.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend messing around with authentication or authorization by yourself. You should use some framework.

Comment: What type of authentication does the page use?  If it uses form authentication, then you will need to provide a response that sets the user name / password in accordance with the response the form is looking for.  My recommendation would be to get a debugging web proxy and trace out the requests and responses that your browser makes when you log into the site interactively.  That is probably the flow you will need to emulate with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Which code you get from the server 401,403,301,302 or 200?

Comment: Can you try the get directly from the browser? You should be prompted with the default basic authentication window and try if you can login that way just to confirm that the problem is in your code and not in the service or in the url itself?

Comment: yes that's no problem, i can login from the browser. Em sorry but because this isn't working with my code is why i am asking :P.

Comment: You should be able to dump the communication between HttpClient and the server. Can you confirm that the header  of the request contains the following piece Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== and that the encoded string is what expected to be?

Comment: I've tried to login in the page and they don't use basic authorization but simple paramenters. So can you see loginname and password parameters  in the communication?

Comment: They use a security token as hidden field in the form and they expect it back as parameter. That's the reason why you are not able to authenticate  with your code

Comment: Ok, so i have to save the security token which i get over the get Request and send it back as paramater with post? This means i have another paramater and value pair in the post Request?

Comment: Yes, this is what I see in the form '<input type="hidden" name="security_token" value="LkvIx/AUjkTFoyOSR++d88j3G7fjoVK3UELtl3cGLQA=">                    <input type="hidden" name="login_ticket" value="8a28e45c99e642f40c849d918cf3bde3">'

Comment: security_token + login_ticket must be sent back in the post